# listviews dont update subitem (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview in VB.net in which i have two columns (Itemname, Coordinates). the Itemname column is populated with predifined names for each rows (total rows=5) and the coordinates column will be filled with the mouse position coordinates when the user select a row and click anywhere on the screen.

```
**Itemname|Coordinates:**
    Item1  (x,y)
    Item2  (x,y)
    Item3  (x,y)
.......
```

My code works only when I select a row and click anywhere for the first time, but when I select the same row and click again to change the coordinate, it doesn't update to the new coordinates.
Here's my code for `Item1`:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

If ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True Then

     Dim mp As Point = MousePosition

     Dim lvitem As ListViewItem

     ListView1.BeginUpdate()

     lvitem = Me.ListView1.Items.Item(0)   
     lvitem.SubItems.Add(mp.ToString)  

     ListView1.Update()
     ListView1.EndUpdate()

End If

End Sub
```

the results:

```
first time selected item1:
    Item1  {X=801,Y=432}
   
second time selected item1:
    Item1  {X=801,Y=432} ===>doesn't update to second click {X=743,Y=231}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: SubItems.Add() cannot be correct, you'll just keep adding sub-items that you can't see since the ListView has only 2 columns.  Get those subitems created early, the form constructor or Load event is the best place.  Use the event only to *update* the subitem text.  Very strange UI btw, so I might be guessing wrong.

Comment: Please give me example,

Comment: i think you are right, it keeps adding sub-items that i can't see. i just want it updates coordinates in the same subitem whenever i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because event you're using.

```
Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

This will invoke sub only when selected item in ListView will be changed. On 2nd click you do not change selected index, it stays the same, that's why it does not update.

Changed event to Click or MouseClick:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles ListView1.Click
```

Comment: sorry i think i was not clear enough, i select the item(0) and it works as expected for the first time i run the form but then i select other item and go back to select the same item(0) the sub is invoked again for that item(0), pick other mouse position but it does not update the coordinate in the selected item().

Comment: No, it's my bad, did not noticed that add line. I think Hans Passant is right, instead of lvitem.SubItems.Add(mp.ToString) try something like lvitem.SubItems(1).Text = mp.ToString

Comment: thank u guys, i put lvitem.SubItems(1).Text = mp.ToString after ListView1.EndUpdate() and it works nicely